# Vue.js How to recalculate the displayed data after changing the select-option?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The task - when changing the unit of measurement, consider the total weight of the products.
Now the data in the array is changing, but new data is displayed on the screen only when click on other input fields

There is a table with data from the array, with the fields: Product name, net weight, quantity.
There is a select in the table with a choice of unit of measure - kg, grams, in order to understand in which units the "net weight" is set
for each value there is a conversion coefficient conversion_num from a separate array

Now, when changing the unit of measure, the unitChange function is launched, which changes the data in the array, but the changes are not displayed on the screen.
I tried with computed function, it work same.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```html
<tr v-for="(comp, i) in st">
 <td>{{comp.name}}</td>
  <td>
   <input v-model.number="comp.weight_netto">
  </td>
  <td>
   <select @change="unitChange($event.target.value, i)" v-model="comp.unit_id">
    <option v-for="val in ul" :value="val.unit_id" v-text="val.name" ></option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input v-model.number="comp.quantity">
  </td>
  <td>{{itemqty(i)}}</td>
 </tr>
```

JS:

```js
methods: {
unitChange(value, i){
 for (var j=0; j<this.ul.length; j++){
  if (this.ul[j].unit_id==value){
  this.st[i].conversion_num=this.ul[j].conversion_num;
  break;
  }
 }
},
itemqty(i){
  return (this.st[i].weight_netto*this.st[i].quantity)/this.st[i].conversion_num;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

Also some things can be refactored

**Example**

```js
const table = Vue.component('product-table', {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [{
        name: 'one',
        weight_netto: 1.23,
        quantity: 4,
        conversion_num: .420,
        unit_id: 1
      },{
        name: 'two',
        weight_netto: 3.21,
        quantity: 5,
        conversion_num: .69,
        unit_id: 2
      }],
      units: [{
          unit_id: 1,
          conversion_num: .420,
          name: 'kg'
        },
        {
          unit_id: 2,
          conversion_num: .69,
          name: 'lb'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  template: `
   <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr :key="product.name" v-for="product in products">
     <td>{{product.name}}</td>
      <td>
       <input v-model.number="product.weight_netto">
      </td>
      <td>
       <select @change="unitChange($event.target.value, product)" v-model="product.unit_id">
        <option :key="unit.unit_id" v-for="unit in units" :value="unit.unit_id" v-text="unit.name" ></option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input v-model.number="product.quantity">
      </td>
      <td>{{itemqty(product)}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`,
  methods: {
    unitChange(unit_id, product) {
      unit_id = Number(unit_id);
      const { conversion_num } = this.units.find(pr => pr.unit_id === unit_id);
      Vue.set(product, 'conversion_num', conversion_num);
    },
    itemqty({ weight_netto, quantity, conversion_num}) {
      return ((weight_netto * quantity) / conversion_num).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#container'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <product-table>
  </product-table>
</div>
```

Comment: also for component instances you can use `this.$set`

Comment: This is what I needed! Many thanks! Now everything works

Answer (score 2):

Don't mutate your products!

You'll end up with rounding errors: changing from one unit to another and back to initial will result in a different value from initial, because of the two roundings.
And it also makes things more difficult for you as everywhere you want to use the product you have to take into account its current unit.

A much cleaner solution is to leave the weight and unit unchanged (in the unit of your choice) and use a method to parse the displayed value, based on currently selected unit.

Your products remain unchanged (neither weight values or weight units change).

Proof of concept:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    products: [
      { id: 1, name: 'one', weight: 20},
      { id: 2, name: 'two', weight: 17}
    ],
    units: [
      {label: 'kgs'},
      {label: 'lbs', factor: 2.20462},
      {label: 'oz', factor: 35.274}
    ],
    currentUnit: {label: 'kgs'}
  }),
  methods: {
    convertToUnit(weight) {
      return (Math.round(weight * (this.currentUnit.factor || 1) * 100) / 100) +
        this.currentUnit.label
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Current unit:
  <select v-model="currentUnit">
    <option v-for="(unit, key) in units" :value="unit" :key="key">{{ unit.label }}</option>
  </select>
  <div v-for="(product, k) in products" :key="k">
    name: <span v-text="product.name"></span>, 
    weight: <span v-text="convertToUnit(product.weight)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Performance-wise, a filter would be better than a method

Comment: @Phil, I'd be interested to know why. Also, would it be better as computed? `convertToUnit() { return weight => (Math.round(weight * (this.currentUnit.factor || 1) * 100) / 100) + this.currentUnit.label }`!?